# Encode a string into character codes

Tags: php, string, character

I want to encode an email address into its corresponding character codes, so when it is printed the char codes are interpreted by the browser, but the robots get the encoded string instead of the interpreted one.

For example (1):

```
abc@abc.com
```

should be sent to the browser as (2) (whitespaces added so the browser shows it):

```
&#97 ;&#98 ;&#99 ;&#64 ;&#97 ;&#98 ;&#99 ;&#46 ;&#99 ;&#111 ;&#109 ;
```

so the human reads (1) and web robots read(2)

There should be an easy function or way to do this, but cannot find one.

Comment: at the end of this document we can find de character codes http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32

Comment: This won't defeat any spambot developed in the last ten years or so.

Comment: i know :) but the boss is asking for this nonesense

Comment: Not sure I understand the "whitespaces added so the browser shows it" bit :-?

Comment: added a whitespace before each ; so you could read what kind of charcode i'm talking about, so the browser shows the code and not the char corresponding to that code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function encode_everything($string){ 
    $encoded = ""; 
    for ($n=0;$n<strlen($string);$n++){ 
        $check = htmlentities($string[$n],ENT_QUOTES); 
       $string[$n] == $check ? $encoded .= "&#".ord($string[$n]).";" : $encoded .= $check; 
    } 
    return $encoded; 
}
```

Found at:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 5):

YOu could try this:

```
<?php
$s = "abc@abc.com";
$obj = array_map(function($x){return "&#". strval(ord($x)) . ";";},str_split($s));
echo implode($obj);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a neat function I wrote to do something similar - not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but it uses php's `ord` function to take each character in a string and output its ascii equivalent:

```
$testString = "I hate – Character – 150" ;

function printAscii($string){      
    for ($n=0;$n<strlen($string);$n++){ 

       echo "<pre>";
       echo ord($string[$n]);
       echo " ---->";
       echo $string[$n];
       echo "</pre>"; 
    }          
} 

$test = printAscii($testString);
```